Causing SQL to prefer casted time seek in view query
We have ETL process executed by Kafka. It can only get and query by datetime2 date data type.
It generates queries like this:
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT *
FROM ViewName
WHERE ViewName.UpdateDate > @P0
      AND ViewName.UpdateDate < @P1
ORDER BY ViewName.UpdateDate ASC',
N'@P0 datetime2,@P1 datetime2','2024-08-05 03:29:00.4033333','2024-08-05 03:31:33.3000000';
  

The problem with this starts with tables where UpdateDate column's type is datetime so we need to cast it to datetime2 in view definition. But SQL server(at least at 2022 version) understands that it can use index on UpdateDate column even if its casted in view definition.
Real issue starts in cases where we have filtered index on UpdateDate. In large tables we've created filtered index to avoid replicating huge amount if data. Because of this we needed to add filter on update date to make index usage possible:
CREATE VIEW [ViewName]
AS
    SELECT  ColumnNames....
           ,UpdateDate = CAST(UpdateDate AS DATETIME2)
    FROM    TableName
    WHERE   UpdateDate > '2022-07-01'
        --Can add UpdateDate > DATEADD(d, -2, GETDATE())
GO

But in this case SQL decides first to scan this index and only then apply parameters filtering causing heavy reads. I can add commented out filter to reduce reads, but I'm searching for solution to make SQL "understand" that it can use parameters instead. We cannot create non filtered index because of table size. Also adding Cast to UpdateDate in where clause causes SQL not to use index at all.
Is there something that can be done in this case code wise?(Forceseek hint throws error)

Please add the actual execution plan(s) via Paste The Plan.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJY_Pil5A
*There are more columns than id and state that I need, so suggested missing index not really an option

Is it possible to have the parameters as strings? eg '20240805 03:29:00.403'

nominative determinism - sounds like a surreal & absurd fight against unconquerable forces

Regarding strings, no - kafka is limited regarding passing data types.
